# Google Scripts Filter Function not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filter

I keep getting this error

TypeError: originalData.filter is not a function (line 8, file "Code")

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var trn = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions");
  var originalData = trn.getRange(2, 1, trn.getLastRow()-1,7).getValues;
  var salesRep = "Jerry Jefferson";
  
  var data = originalData.filter(function(item){ return item[1] === salesRep && item[4] > 300; });



  var targetSheet = ss.insertSheet(salesRep);
  targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Were you trying to `.getValues()` and filter?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because your originalData decleration isn't complete, you forgot the () at the end of `getValues`.

Correction would be:  `var originalData = trn.getRange(2, 1, trn.getLastRow()-1,7).getValues;`

So now your script is trying to run a `filter()` on a function instead of it's data.

Comment: It worked. Can't believe I missed that! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think `.filter()` is not a function. You need to use `.getFilter()`, which gives you a filtered range.

```
function FilterSheet() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1:F10').createFilter();
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(['605','804','472']
    .build
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, 
    criteria);
}
```